# How are S-Parameters and Reactance related, can one be calculated from the other?

Tags: rf, filter, impedance, reactance, s-parameters

I know that, for example, \$X_L=2\pi f L\$ will calculate reactance of an ideal inductor, but can this be calculated for a real component model? Given the S-Parameter values at some frequency from an S2P file, can you calculate the reactance of the component at that frequency?

For example, in Mag-Angle format, [this 120 nH inductor](https://www.coilcraft.com/en-us/products/rf/ceramic-core-chip-inductors/0402-(1005)/0402dc/) has the following S-parameter values at 100MHz as seen in its .s2p file:

| S-Param | \$\|S\|\$ | Phase \$\angle\$ in degrees |
| --- | --- | --- |
| \$S_{11}\$ | 0.588600478 | 50.2086462 |
| \$S_{21}\$ | 0.770096917 | -35.9648121 |
| \$S_{12}\$ | 0.770096917 | -35.9648121 |
| \$S_{22}\$ | 0.588600478 | 50.2086462 |

Reactance for 120nH at 100MHz should be somewhere near here, but I want to know the component's reactance based on the S2P model:

\$2\pi×(100×10^6)×(120×10^{−9}) \approx 75.36 \Omega\$

**Questions:**

- Is it possible to calculate the (probably complex) reactance based on the S-Parameters above?
- If so, how?

See also: [Can admittance (Y) be used to calculate reactance when L and C values are calculated from the Y12 and Y11 parameters like normal as X=XL-XC?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/620665/256265)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maxim [Tutorial 2866](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/tutorials/2/2866.html), equation 2; along with other sources; cover this. Essentially:

$$ Zin = Zo \left( {1+S_{11}} \over {1-S_{11}} \right)  $$

where *Zo* is your measurement system impedance, generally 50 Ω.

If my arithmetic is right, \$ Zin = 55.1 + j76.3 \$.

Comment: Interesting, so reactance is completely reflection-based? So, input impedance the same as reactance? Is S11 the only s-parameter responsible for reactance?

Comment: S<sub>11</sub> is the reflection coefficient. Reflections happen because of impedance mismatch between the source and the system under test. The inductor data supplied shows it's an imperfect inductor, i.e., it has a significant real (lossy)component at the frequency under test.

Comment: Is S11 the only s-parameter responsible for reactance?

Comment: @KJ7LNW S22 can be used to find the impedance of the output of the network.